# Android sqlite could not open database error 14

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, database-connection

I'm working Sqlite. I have mydb.sqllite file in assets folder and I try to read my database from asset folder. I wrote some code which can read database and my code worked perfect. Then I deleted my mydb.sqllite from asset folder and  inserted new .sqllite file(same name) and now I have  exception

```
public class CredoDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public int GetCursor;
private Context myContext;
public String DB_PATH = "data/data/my package/databases/";

public static String DB_NAME = "mydb.sqlite";
private SQLiteDatabase db;

private static String usm_Users = "usm_Users";

public CredoDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    if (db != null && db.isOpen())
        close();

    this.myContext = context;
    // DB_NAME = db_name;

    try {

        createDataBase();
        openDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // System.out.println("Exception in creation of database : "+
        // e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        // System.out.println("Database Exist");
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            copyDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
    InputStream input = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outputFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
    // System.out.println(DB_NAME + "Database Copied !");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    // Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

public boolean isOpen() {
    if (db != null)
        return db.isOpen();
    return false;
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (db != null)
        db.close();
    super.close();
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        // System.out.println("My Pathe is:- " + myPath);
        // System.out.println("Open");
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        // System.out.println("checkDB value:" + checkDB);
        // System.out.println("My Pathe is:- " + myPath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // database does't exist yet.
    }

    if (checkDB != null) {
        // System.out.println("Closed");
        checkDB.close();
        // System.out.println("My db is:- " + checkDB.isOpen());
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

public Cursor execCursorQuery(String sql) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        GetCursor = cursor.getCount();
        Log.i("Inside execCursorQuery try", sql);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Inside execCursorQuery exception", e.getMessage());
    }
    return cursor;
}

public void execNonQuery(String sql) {
    try {
        db.execSQL(sql);
        // Log.d("SQL", sql);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log.e("Err", e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        // closeDb();
    }
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong? If anyone knows solution please help me.

Comment: Thank you for keeping the stack trace a secret.

Comment: What happens if you put the old database back, in place of the new one?

Comment: @CL. i don't unserstand you

Comment: see [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: @DerGolem Golem  both databases have  same names. when i put old database also have a error

Comment: I understood that they have the **same name**. But they don't have the **same contents**.

Comment: may the file on which this error occur is a primary database file of SQLite database or it can be the temporary disk files.